# Magento2 CSS groups in styles-m.css in wrong order

Tags: magento2, css, less

my themes "_extend.less" file looks like this:

```
//common
& when (@media-common = true) {
...
}
//mobile
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {
...
}
//tablet
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
...
}
```

in the generated styles-m.css everything under the common block is put at the end of file after the @media blocks, which breaks the order of precedence for mobile styles.

shouldn't the common block come first in styles-m and than the @media rules in the generated file?